# Column X contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im facing an issue with my SQL query... When i try to run it, the following message appears: `"com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Column 16 contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [65:31]"`

The query in question is this one: https://pastebin.com/Nm6UxDEr
(too long to paste here).

Can someone help me solve this aggregation problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: i really cannot do it, im new in SQL :(

Comment: New to SQL, and you write a huge SQL query like that?!? Take baby steps, and verify each step before you take the next.

Comment: I haven't wrote it from 0... here where i work, we use a lot of queries... i studied and started to build it like a 'frankenstein', but im always learning.

Comment: So what change did you do, which caused the error message?

Comment: I added the SHP_LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID and      

 RIGHT JOIN WHOWNER.BT_SHP_LG_SHIPMENTS_ROUTES logs ON A.shp_shipment_id = logs.shp_shipment_id
      INNER JOIN WHOWNER.LK_SHP_COMPANIES comp ON comp.SHP_company_ID = logs.shp_company_ID
      INNER JOIN WHOWNER.LK_SHP_LG_ROUTES XPT ON XPT.shp_lg_route_id = logs.shp_lg_route_id
      LEFT JOIN WHOWNER.LK_SHP_LG_RTG_ROUTE RR ON RR.SHP_LG_ROUTE_ID = XPT.SHP_LG_PLANNED_ROUTE
      LEFT JOIN WHOWNER.LK_SHP_LG_RTG_ORDER RO ON RO.SHP_LG_ORDER_ID = RR.SHP_LG_ROUTING_ORDER_ID

Answer (score -1):

Line 65 has a `group by` columns list:

```
Select ....
WHERE A.SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID IN ('SMS1')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17)
```

Since some columns were added the `group by` has to be adjusted to:

```
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,17,18
)
```

Your script from line 2 to 65 should be runnable on its own. It cannot be tested here, because there are no table data given. However, in a first attempt some sample data can be made up and the script should be runnable. All calculated fields are replaced by a test variable:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT SHP_SHIPMENT_ID AS ID_PACOTE,
  TMS_SELLER_INFO_NAME AS SELLER,
  SHP_PICKING_TYPE_ID AS TIPO_PICKING,
  SHP_LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID AS ORIGEM,
  SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID AS DESTINO,
  SHP_LG_ORIGIN_CODE AS XPT,
  A1 AS STATUS_LT,
  A2 AS PROMESSA_INICIAL,
  A3 AS PROMESSA_FINAL,
  A4 AS PROMESSA,
  MIN(A) AS A_ETIQUETAR,
  MIN(A) AS PRONTO_PARA_COLETA,
  MIN(A) AS COLETADO,
  MIN(A) AS EM_DEPOSITO,
  MIN(A) AS CAMINHO_PARA_ESTACAO,
  MIN(A) AS ENTROU_NA_ESTACAO,
  (A5) AS PRIMEIRA_VISITA,
  (A6) AS DATA_ENTREGA,
FROM (
  SELECT
    1001 AS A,
    1 SHP_SHIPMENT_ID,
    2 TMS_SELLER_INFO_NAME,
    3 SHP_PICKING_TYPE_ID,
    4 SHP_LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID,
    5 SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID,
    6 SHP_LG_ORIGIN_CODE,
    11 A1,
    12 A2,
    13 A3,
    14 A4,
    15 A5,
    16 A6
    Union ALL Select 1000,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112) 
    # WHERE  A.SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID IN ('SMS1') 
# GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17 # Error: COLUMN 16 contains an aggregation FUNCTION, which IS NOT allowed IN GROUP BY
   GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,17,18,10
```

With the comment out line for the `group by` the error for column 16 occures. Indeed the `group by` statement should be adjusted by `17,18,10`. The query should work then. Using the formula this can be written and tested as

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
 
  SHP_SHIPMENT_ID AS ID_PACOTE,
  TMS_SELLER_INFO_NAME AS SELLER,
  SHP_PICKING_TYPE_ID AS TIPO_PICKING,
  SHP_LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID AS ORIGEM,
  SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID AS DESTINO,
  SHP_LG_ORIGIN_CODE AS XPT,
 
    CASE WHEN CAST(SHP_DATE_FIRST_VISIT_ID AS DATE) < CAST(EST_DELIVERY_DATE AS DATE) THEN 'EARLY' 
         WHEN CAST(SHP_DATE_FIRST_VISIT_ID AS DATE) > CAST((CASE WHEN EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE IS NULL THEN DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) ELSE DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) END) AS DATE) THEN 'DELAY' 
         ELSE 'ON_TIME' 
    END AS STATUS_LT,
 
    DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_DATE, INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS PROMESSA_INICIAL,
    DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE, INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS PROMESSA_FINAL,
    CASE WHEN EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE IS NULL THEN DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) ELSE DATETIME_ADD(EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) END AS PROMESSA,
 
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'ready_to_print'  THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS A_ETIQUETAR,
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'for_pickup'      THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS PRONTO_PARA_COLETA,
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'picked_up'       THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS COLETADO,
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'on_hub'          THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS EM_DEPOSITO,
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'on_way'          THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS CAMINHO_PARA_ESTACAO,
    MIN(CASE WHEN SHP_LG_STATUS = 'at_station'      AND SHP_LG_SUB_STATUS ='sorting' THEN DATETIME_ADD(CAST(SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT AS DATETIME), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)  END) AS ENTROU_NA_ESTACAO,
 
    DATETIME_ADD(SHP_DATE_FIRST_VISIT_ID,   INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS PRIMEIRA_VISITA,
    DATETIME_ADD(SHP_DATETIME_DELIVERED_ID, INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS DATA_ENTREGA, 
 
    FROM 
    (
  SELECT
    1001 AS A,
    1 SHP_SHIPMENT_ID,
    2 TMS_SELLER_INFO_NAME,
    3 SHP_PICKING_TYPE_ID,
    4 SHP_LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID,
    5 SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID,
    6 SHP_LG_ORIGIN_CODE,
'ready_to_print'   SHP_LG_STATUS ,
'' as SHP_LG_SUB_STATUS,
current_datetime() SHP_DATE_FIRST_VISIT_ID,
current_datetime() EST_DELIVERY_DATE, 
current_datetime() EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE,
current_datetime()  SHP_LG_SHIPMENT_CHK_DT,
current_datetime() SHP_DATETIME_DELIVERED_ID
    Union ALL Select 1000,101,102,103,104,105,106,'on_hub','',current_datetime(),current_datetime(),current_datetime(),current_datetime(),current_datetime()
   ) 
    # WHERE  SHP_LG_FACILITY_ID IN ('SMS1') 
# GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17 # Error: COLUMN 16 contains an aggregation FUNCTION, which IS NOT allowed IN GROUP BY
   GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,17,18,10
```

Some further guides to shorten your query:

- Use `ifnull(columnA, 0)` when possible instead of a `case when columnA is null`.

```
CAST((CASE WHEN B.EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE IS NULL THEN DATETIME_ADD(B.EST_DELIVERY_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) ELSE DATETIME_ADD(B.EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE, INTERVAL '21' HOUR) END) AS DATE)
```

shortens to

```
CAST(DATETIME_ADD(IFNULL(EST_DELIVERY_OFFSET_DATE,B.EST_DELIVERY_DATE), INTERVAL '21' HOUR) AS DATE)
```

- use list in case statement:

```
  CASE
    WHEN DESTINO in  ('SMG1','SMG6','SMG12')   THEN 'MG'
    WHEN DESTINO in ('SMG4','SMG7','SMG8','SMG13')   THEN 'MGI'
    WHEN DESTINO = 'SMG2'   THEN 'MGII'
    WHEN DESTINO = 'SMG3'   THEN 'MGII'
    WHEN DESTINO = 'SMG5'   THEN 'MGII'
    WHEN DESTINO = 'SMG9'   THEN 'MGII'
   END AS REGIONAL
```

- use `date_diff` instead three times a `date_add` to figure out a time difference in a case statement. Nested select statement are also allowed to calculate the difference and then use that value in the next select statement.
- An user SQL-UDF function may look nicer for the six `A.SHP_LG_STATUS = 'ready_to_print'` statements.

Comment: I did all you said, but the error persists, saying about the Group BY Columns

Comment: Can you help me Samuel?

Comment: here you go. If it is still not working, please try to give a query code here that is showing your issue and error. It does not help to provide a 100 line code and state that on line 65 there is the error ... and we cannot try out, because the tables are accessible. A good way is to provide some sample data, which can be of course random numbers and only be the right data format.

Comment: The problem is i have permission only to run queries and download the results,i have limited access

Comment: Please run the first query given here. Does it work? Then the 2nd one. Does this work? Then replace the `FROM .... WHERE ` part with your part of the query and also include the `WITH SHP AS (``part. Does this work? Problems are solved step wise. You have a query over 100 lines long, consisting of two `with table` statements. In a first step save the table in the with statement as a new table. If you do not have access to do so, call your admin and its common practice to give users a extra project (working zone) for writing test tables.